# Spawning clones without overlapping - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to spawn clones of a Game object in random positions on the screen, without having any of the clones overlapping?

Answer (score 0):

You could add each spawned clone to a list, and check through the list for each clones position when spawning a new clone to make sure the clone you are spawning does not fall within the bounds of an existing clone.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this thread (those guys made some really good scripts regarding your problem) :

https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-to-randomly-instantiate-cubes-that-dont-overlap.263161/